# Pronunciation 'heroin' vs. 'heroine'

Tags: pronunciation

Is there a difference in how you pronounce the drug and the female hero?

Like, for instance, if I see a movie with a great actress and I want to say to my friend

> That was the best **heroine** I have ever seen.

Can it be confused with

> That was the best **heroin** I have ever seen.

?

Or will my friend consider me a junkie?

Comment: Use *she*, not *that* with *heroine*. Also, I doubt you'd use *see* with *heroin*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a difference in how you pronounce the drug and the female hero?

Not really. Some ideolects might distinguish them, but they are both listed as "Brit. /ˈhɛrəʊɪn/ , U.S. /ˈhɛrəwən/" by the OED, and similarly by other dictionaries.

And for that matter, they are both formed from *hero* + *-ine*, though different cases of the *-ine* suffix in each.

> Or will my friend consider me a junkie?

Not terribly likely, because there aren't many contexts in which they are confusable, unless perhaps you express a desire to inject Joan of Arc or smoke Wonder Woman.